# How to merge .001, .002 ... files from multiple drives?

Tags: 7-zip, merge

Is there a way to merge multiple part files (`.0001`, `.0002`, etc.) from multiple drives?

I have three part files of 5 GB each, but I have only 20 GB on the hard drive. I would need another 10 GB to accomodate three-part files and the merged file. I'm planning to have two-part files on a flash drive and one on a hard drive so that there is enough space to merge them.

I'm using 7-Zip to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the split files are `.part1.rar` , `.part2.rar` (use **WinRAR**), as **WinRAR** allows you to do this. WinRAR will detect the missing files and ask you to select the folder with those missing files.

But with `.001`, `002`, I don't even know who made these type of file.

There are many programs can join / merge these files, but not like **WinRAR**.

If you really need to join these files, contact the person who "invented" `*.001`, `*.002`,
but I don't think that's possible, so you could buy a new hard drive, or delete some data in your drive, sorry.

But, why do you only have 20 GB in your hard drive, that's too small! :D

Comment: .001 etc are common (older) extensions for (among other things) .rar files

Comment: I tried WinRar and it works like a champ! Thanks for the help!! I have only 20GB free in my 750 GB hard drive :)

Answer (score 0):

To join files with `*.001` `*.002` extention you should use [FFSJ: The Fastest File Splitter and Joiner](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/~hoangle/filesj/).